# ML error: "Cast string to float is not supported"

Tags: python, string, casting

UnimplementedError: Cast string to float is not supported

```
dftrain = pd.read_csv('train.csv') # training data
dfeval = pd.read_csv('eval.csv') # testing data
```

can I change something here?

Comment: Please [edit] to provide samples of your data and include the full error traceback, not just the last line, to make a [mcve]

Comment: You are passing inputs to model which are literally has string values, network cannot be input string values. You can convert strings into numbers with OneHotEncoder. Thanks!